# Invalid syntax in jupyter notbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

[image]

I have got invalid syntax below code

```
ax = sns.heatmap(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train,pred_train_RF),annot=True,fmt='d',cmap='Greys'

plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
plt.ylabel('Actual Label')

plt.title('Random Forest_Confusion Matrix on Train Data')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Count the parenthesis on the first line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is missing a closing parenthesis. Try the following:

```py
# sns.heatmap() wasn't closed previously 
ax = sns.heatmap(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train,pred_train_RF),annot=True,fmt='d',cmap='Greys')

plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
plt.ylabel('Actual Label')

plt.title('Random Forest_Confusion Matrix on Train Data')

plt.show()
```

If you use a full IDE or Code Editor (like VSCode or PyCharm) they can sometimes catch these errors for you.